# How to activate a button with jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to show a `Next-Button`once the user has clicked the `checkbox` of the "I agree with..." text.
I tried `()toggle` and `show/hide` but couldn't make it work. Any idea how to fix this?

jQuery

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#i_agree_check").click(function(){
    $("next_2_btn_info").hide();
  });
  $("#i_agree_check").click(function(){
    $("next_2_btn_info").show();
  });
});
</script>
```

HTML

```
    <div class="checkbox_agree show"><input type="checkbox" id="i_agree_check"</><?php echo $lang ['i_agree']; ?></div>

    <div class="edit_btn"> <!-- Not active placeholder -->
        <a href="#" title="<?php echo $lang ['complete_step']; ?>"><?php echo $lang ['next']; ?></a>
    </div>

    <div class="next_2_btn_info" id="next_2_btn_info">
        <a href="order_banner_2.php"><?php echo $lang ['next']; ?></a>
    </div>
```

Comment: Missing `#` before your selectors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this (updated):

```
$("#next_2_btn_info").hide();
$("#i_agree_check").click(function(){
    $("#next_2_btn_info").toggle();
  });
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer, the problem I have now is that the button does show from the beginning and hides when I click. What I need is exactly the opposite of that. This "next" button should show only when the user checks the ´checkbox´. How can I do that?

Answer (score 1):

```
$("next_2_btn_info").hide(); //Change

$("#next_2_btn_info").hide();
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this, You need to add `#` or `.` before the selector element like `$("#next_2_btn_info")`

```
    $(function(){
      $("#i_agree_check").click(function(){
             $("#next_2_btn_info").toggle();     
      });
    });
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer, the problem I have now is that the button does show from the beginning and hides when I click. What I need is exactly the opposite of that. This "next" button should show only when the user checks the ´checkbox´. How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

You're registering two contradictory `click` events with your checkbox and you don't use the id of the button. Try this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#i_agree_check").click(function(){
         $("#next_2_btn_info").toggle();     
  });
});
```

Notice how it's `#next_2_btn_info` instead of `next_2_btn_info`. Also, `.toggle()` shows/hides based on the current state of the object.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer, the problem I have now is that the button does show from the beginning and hides when I click. What I need is exactly the opposite of that. This "next" button should show only when the user checks the ´checkbox´. How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

You are setting up the click handler twice in a row on $("#i_agree_check"). Try setting up a single click handler and test the value of the checkbox to determine if it has been checked or not.

```
$('#i_agree_check').click(function(){
 if($("#i_agree_check").is(':checked')) { 
  $('next_2_btn_info').show();
 } else {
  $('next_2_btn_info').hide();
 }
}
```